# Shone or shined?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

This is my first time posting and I need help. *’The sunlight shone dimly through the curtain.’* Does it make sense? Is it suppose to be shined instead of shone? I feel something is wrong but I don’t really know.

Answer (score 1):

The two forms of past tense/past participle of *shine* are both valid: shone and shined. **Shone** usually appears in the verb's intransitive usages, while **shined** tends to be transitive, not without exceptions of course. "*One shined their shoes.*" and "*The light shone brightly.*"

The verb conjugation is perfectly fine in your sentence, but I am not fond of the subject and the complement. I would say:

> The sun shone dimly through the curtains.

The [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shine) has a nice passage about this:

> The verb shine has two past and past participle forms, **shone** and **shined**. The form shone is generally preferred when the verb is used without an object, as in the sun shone brightly. When shine is used transitively, the form shined is usual when the meaning is ‘to polish’, but both forms are used when the meaning is ‘to direct (a light)’. Conventions regarding usage of shined and shone are generally less rigid in US English than in British English, and it is not unusual to see either form used irrespective of meaning even in carefully edited texts

Answer (score 0):

Shined is pretty much used only for objects - if the curtain was shiny, you could use 'the curtain shined', but when you are referring to the subject (ie. what the sentence is about), then you use *shone*

Hence, it is more correct in this instance to use shone

Hope this helps!